# how do I set a variable for image base URL

Tags: angular, angular-universal

i want to add variable for image base url, Iam working on an angular application , in that site contain lots of images in each component , how do i set a variable for image base URL.

i tried to add base-URL variable in separate "ts" file , but did not work,

Comment: You can set the base url as a variable in the environment files, and then import the environment variable in each component where you use it.

Comment: if the environment files is not present in the application file , what can i do ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The Angular CLI creates an environments folder for you when you create an app.

Comment: export const environment = {
    ImagebaseUrl:"/assets/images",
}; this is what i write on enivironment.ts file

Comment: how to import the varibale into an html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from the comments you do it like this:

You add the `ImagebaseUrl` variable in the environment like this:

[image]

Then depending on the depth of the component in the Angular application you import it like this:

[image]

And then you can use it inside the component however you like.

It is very helpful if you use an IDE which can help you with automatic imports.

Comment: Property 'ImagebaseUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.

10   imageBaseUrl = environment.ImagebaseUrl; this is what i got when run the above code

Comment: Can you check if in the environment file you have the object environment and inside you have added the imageBaseUrl. 

Also, did you import it in the app component or in any other component, if so, you have to have the correct folder structure of the import.

Last question. Did this error occur locally or in production, because I forgot to say that you also have to add in environment.prod.ts